# Alternation in regexes seems to be terribly slow in big files

Tags: regex, raku

I am trying to use this regex:

```
my @vulnerabilities = ($g ~~ m:g/\s+("Low"||"Medium"||"High")\s+/);
```

On chunks of [files such as this one](https://github.com/JJ/2020-WCCI-variable-attack-surface/blob/master/code/results/results_2020_02_05/results_simple_16_2_random_1.txt), the chunks that go from one "sorted" to the next. Every one must be a few hundred kilobytes, and all of them together take from 1 to 3 seconds all together (divided by 32 per iteration).

How can this be sped up?

Comment: Do they need to be in order that they're found?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen not really.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inspection of the example file reveals that the strings only occur as a whole line, starting with a tab and a space.  From your responses I further gathered that you're really only interested in counts.  If that is the case, then I would suggest something like this solution:

```
my %targets = "\t Low", "Low", "\t Medium", "Medium", "\t High", "High";
my %vulnerabilities is Bag = $g.lines.map: {
    %targets{$_} // Empty
}
dd %vulnerabilities;  # ("Low"=>2877,"Medium"=>54).Bag
```

This runs in about .25 seconds on my machine.

It always pays to look at the problem domain thoroughly!

Answer (score 3):

This can be simplified a little bit. You use `\s+` before and after, but is this necessary? I think you need just to assure word boundary or just one whitespace, thus, you can use

```
\s("Low"||"Medium"||"High")\s
```

or you can use `\b` instead of `\s`.

Second step is not to use capturing group, use non-capturing grous instead, because regex engine wastes time and memory for "remembering" groups, so you could try with:

```
\s(?:"Low"||"Medium"||"High")\s
```

Comment: Note that non capturing groups are indicated in Raku with `[ ]`, that is `\s [ 'Low' || 'Medium' || 'High' ] \s`

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** I've compared solutions on a recent rakudo, using your sample data. The ugly brute-force solution I present here is about twice as fast as the delightfully elegant solution Liz has presented. You could probably improve times another order of magnitude or more by breaking your data up and parallel processing it. I also discuss other options if that's not enough.

## Alternations seems like a red herring

When I eliminated the alternation (leaving just `"Low"`) and ran the code on a recent rakudo, the time taken was about the same. So I think that's a red herring and have not studied that aspect further.

## Parallel processing looks promising

It's clear from your data that you could break it up, splitting at some arbitrary line, and then pattern match each piece in parallel, and then combine results.

That could net you a substantial win, depending on various factors related to your system and the data you process.

But I haven't explored this option.

## The fastest results I've seen

The fastest results I've seen are with this code:

```
my %counts;
$g ~~ m:g / "\t " [ 'Low' || 'Medium' || 'High' ] \n { %counts{$/}++ } /;
say %counts.map: { .key.trim, .value }
```

This displays:

```
((Low 2877) (Medium 54))
```

This approach incorporates similar changes to those Michał Turczyn discussed, but pushed harder:

- I've thrown away *all* capturing, not only not bothering to capture the `'Low'` or whatever, but also throwing away *all* results of the match.
- I've replaced the `\s+` patterns with concrete characters rather than character classes. I've done so on the basis my casual tests with a recent rakudo suggested that's a bit faster.

## Going beyond raku's regexes

Raku is designed for full Unicode generality. And its regex engine is extremely powerful. But it looks like your data is just ASCII and your pattern is a typical very simple regex. So you're using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. This shouldn't really matter -- the sledgehammer is supposed to be just fine as a nutcracker too -- but raku's regex engine remains very poorly optimized thus far.

Perhaps this nut is just a simple example and you're just curious about pushing raku's built in regex capabilities to their maximum current performance.

But if not, and you need yet more speed, and the speedups from this or other better solutions in raku, coupled with parallel processing, aren't enough to get you where you need to go, it's worth considering either not using raku or using it with another tool.

One idiomatic way to use raku with another tool is to use an **Inline**, with the obvious one in this case being `Inline::Perl5`. Using that you can try perl's fast default built in regex engine or even use its regex plugin capability to plug in a really fast regex engine.

And, given the simplicity of the pattern you're matching, you could even eschew regexes altogether by writing a quick bit of glue to some low-level raw text searching tool (perhaps saving character offsets and then generating corresponding raku match objects from the results).

Comment: @raiph your regex take 0.03 sec (unbeatable in this example) but it is triggered for every `"\t "` found. I would like to __START__ (trigger) it only if `Low, Medium or High` is found and __THEN__ look behind the match. I don't manage. Just adding some `<?after>` and I get 5sec. Do you have an idea how to do that ?

Comment: @Tinmarino My guess is you're thinking that might be faster. Maybe if the raku (NQP) regex engine wasn't so poorly optimized you'd be right. But tricks like look behind usually seriously slow down a regex engine, so maybe not, at least not for the sample data. I could well believe there'd need to be a much lower percentage of "hits" after `"\t "`s to make it worth the additional cost of doing a look behind, as your 5sec suggests. Have you tried the same trick with some other regex engine, eg using either perl's default built in regex engine or a plugin replacement?

Comment: @jjmerelo I've updated my answer to show what I was suggesting for counting.